# Dynamic background slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I'm trying to do a simple slidshow by changing the background image whithout having to hard code each image path. I named all images "slideShow" with a number at the end(slideShow1.png/slideShow2.png). This is my code, but it's only fading out the original background image and not repalcing it with a new one. Please help
Thanks.

```
var imgArr = new Array();
for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
var count = i+1;
imgArr[i] = new Image();
imgArr[i].src = "http://localhost/website/css/images/slideShow" + count + ".png";
}

 function changeImg(){
 for(var i=0; i < imgArr.length; i++){
 $('#slideshow').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function(){
 $(this).css('background',"url('" + imgArr[i].src +"') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent")
 }).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
}
};
var startRolling = setInterval(changeImg, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of changes to your code:

Don't do new Array(). Just use var x = []; In either case, you don't need this here.

You don't need to create image objects to set background images. You *can*, if you wanted to preload the images, but this may be an over complication in your case.

Modified code:

```
(function(){
    var count = 0,
    slideshow = $('#slideshow'),

    startRolling = setInterval(function(){

        count > 5?
            count = 0:
            count++;

        slideshow.css('background-image', 'url(http://localhost/website/css/images/slideShow' + count + '.png');

    }, 3000);
})();
```

Note that I am not adding in the fade-in/fade-out animations in this example. I leave it as an exercise to the OP to figure that part out.

Also, note that you should *only* be changing the css properties that need changing. Hence, the extra definitions of "no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent" need to be set in your stylesheet, and not directly via the style object. Remember, the trick to *any* kind of DOM manipulations is to do it as little as feasibly possible.